# AttributeError: 'list' object has ho attribute 'click'

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to use click() command in Selenium WebDriver using Python. But I am getting this error,  please help me out

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:....\Auto.py", line 7, in <module>
    sign.click()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'click'
```

Here is my program

```
from selenium import webdriver as wd

driver = wd.Chrome()
driver.get('https://youtube.com')

sign = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="button"]')
sign.click()
```

Comment: Are you sure you are using `.find_element_by...` and not find `.find_elementS_by...`?

Comment: I would print out the `sign` to see what you really found.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of find_elements_by you need to use find_element_by. Also `xpath` which you are trying to use not correct. Please refer below solution to click on sign in button on youtube.

```
driver.get('https://www.youtube.com/')


wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)
singIn = wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//ytd-button-renderer[@class='style-scope ytd-masthead style-suggestive size-small']//yt-formatted-string[@id='text']")))
singIn.click()
```

**Note** : add below imports to your solution :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
```